# Using spring with Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, guard, spring-gem

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2.15 and I want to use spring in order to speed my development. I'm using guard 1.7.0 and rspec 2.13.1.

This is my `Guardfile`:

```
guard 'rspec', cmd: 'bundle exec spring rspec --color --fail-fast', all_on_start: false, keep_failed: false, all_after_pass: false, rubygems: false, bundler: false do
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{app/(.+)/(.+)\.rb})                  { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{spec/(.+)/(.+)_spec\.rb})
end
```

I addded the `spring-commands-rspec` gem on my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end
```

I `bundle install`ed and created the binstubs (`bundle exec spring binstub --all`), run `guard` and saved a test in order for `guard` to run it. Once this was done, I checked `spring status`, but it said *Spring is not running*.

I modified the `Guardfile` to remove the `rubygems` and `bundler` options, even removed the `bundle exec` call in `cmd` option, but nothing made spring run.

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can put RSpec options in a `.rspec` file or `.rspec-local` file like this:

```
--color
--fail-fast
```

That way they are used no matter where rspec is called from.

Second, the best way to work with Guard and Spring is to make sure spring first works properly *outside* guard, e.g.

```
spring stop
bin/rspec # if it was generated with spring binstub
spring status
```

If that doesn't work - maybe it didn't get binstubbed properly. Does RSpec work by itself? (without spring).

If that doesn't work, try the steps here: https://github.com/rails/spring#troubleshooting

(In case spring isn't starting for some other reason)